# How to create a Rails 3.2.* app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

Hurray! Rails 4 is here...

Now, how do I create a 3.2.13 app since

`rails new my app`

installs `rails '4.0.0.rc1'`

Also, I already have rails gem 3.2.13 installed

[image: ](![gem list]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rails _3.2.13_ new app`

(I'm using [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv))

Answer (score 5):

you should do:
gem install 'rails' -v '3.2.13'

You should use a clean gemset, if you are using rvm, you can try:

```
rvm gemset create <name>
rvm gemset use <name>
```

Now you have a clean gemset, it's time to install rails,

```
gem install rails -v '3.2.13'
```

and then create a rails app,

```
rails new app_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call specific gem (applies to any gem as far as I know) with following syntax:

```
rails _3.2.13_ -v
```

After this, it’s matter of using `bundle exec rails` instead of just `rails`, inside the application.